# Is there an one line way to read-in remote CSV files using Ruby's Standard Library CSV, or must I use FasterCSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

Neither CSV file method seems to work with a URI.

A Line at a Time:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

All at Once

```
arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")"
```

Comment: Add `require "open-uri"` and try again. If `CSV`'s methods use `open` in the background, you are good.

Answer (score 2):

small change to Ashley's answer solved the similar question I had

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://somedata.com/file.csv"
csv_data = open(url)
csv_rows = CSV.parse(csv_data.read)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://somedata.com/file.csv"
csv_data = open(url)
csv_rows = CSV.read(csv_data.path,  { headers: true,
                                  converters: :numeric,
                                  header_converters: :symbol }
               )
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try [RemoteTable](https://github.com/seamusabshere/remote_table):

```
t = RemoteTable.new("http://somedata.com/file.csv")
t.each do |row|
  puts row['foo']
end
```

It can also read remote XLS, XLSX, Google Docs (spreadsheets), TSV, XML, HTML, etc. Lots of examples are in the README.